# How do I create my own mining-pool?

Tags: mining, mining-pools, p2pool

I have about 900+ Mh worth of power and I'm thinking of creating my own pool and putting all my miners in the pool instead of pooling with others. However I've found no instruction on how to do this. Can someone help me with this?

Or is there anything like p2pool available?

Comment: when i run this code : geth --rpc --rpcaddr "my ip" --rpcport 8545 then i got an error like (anonymous): Line 1:13 Unexpected identifier (and 1 more errors) plz help ps: sorry for my bad english

Comment: @coreytaylor211 I guess what you are looking for us the [`ask question` button](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just use `geth` if you don't want to join a pool. This is called "solo mining". It's done this way:

1. One master server is running `geth`:

   ```
   geth --rpc --rpcaddr "IP ADDRESS" --rpcport PORT
   ```
2. Other computers (miners) are only running `ethminer`:

   ```
   ethminer.exe -G -F http://[IP ADDRESS:PORT]
   ```